# Error when attempting to use the data binding provided context variable with BaseObservable

Tags: android, android-databinding

Per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374483/android-databinding-where-to-get-context#comment56066207_32385583) and the [Android Data Binding tutorial](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#variables) I should have a `context` variable available when data binding:

> A special variable named context is generated for use in binding expressions as needed. The value for context is the Context from the root View's getContext(). The context variable will be overridden by an explicit variable declaration with that name.

I'm using a class extending `BaseObservable` to set my data, but no matter how I try to bring in the `context` variable in my `@Bindable` method I get the compile time error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
>     @Bindable associated with method must follow JavaBeans convention getStyledName(android.content.Context)

As far as I can tell, I am following JavaBeans conventions. I've tracked the error down to [this line in BrUtil](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/f60d841/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/databinding/BrUtil.java#59) but that didn't give me much help either.

I've tried changing my method and parameter names, I've tried adding in a `<variable>` for the `context` and a `<import>` for `android.content.Context`, but none of that made any difference. My `User.java` below has two `@Bindable` methods, the bare `getName()` works fine but the one that tries to use the `context` variable doesn't, so I don't think it's an issue with the rest of my data binding setup either.

Relevant code:

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable name="user" type="com.kasra.androidsandbox.User" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@{user.getStyledName(context)}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

`User.java`:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Bindable
    public CharSequence getStyledName(Context ctx) {
        int color = ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.branded_pink);

        Spannable textSpan = new SpannableString(name);
        textSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, textSpan.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return textSpan;
    }

}
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    User user = new User("Kasra");
    binding.setUser(user);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Comment: I believe this might be a bug with the data binding library itself, so I've also crossposted this over to the Android bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220621

Comment: You should be able to fix it by just removing the `@Bindable` annotation

Comment: @ChadBingham while in this scenario I don't need the `@Bindable` annotation, in my actual application I would greatly benefit from having it, I think.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a bug or intended behavior, but I observed this behavior myself, so you're not crazy.

A workaround is to create a method that is NOT marked `@Bindable` in your User -- the one that requires the Context.  This method won't be subject to the JavaBeans naming conventions.

**Important**: In order to make sure it's updated appropriately, it should take as inputs any @Bindable fields that might change.

`User.java`

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public CharSequence getStyledName(Context ctx, String name) {
        // construct styled name here
    }
}
```

and in your layout:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@{user.getStyledName(context, user.name)}" />
```

Comment: still not a formal solution found?

Comment: It appears to be intended behavior. See BRUtil.isGetter(PsiMethod) and BRUtil.isBooleanGetter(PsiMethod) in the file the OP linked. Both require that the method have 0 params. So according to their interpretation, the Beans getter must have no params.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Android 2.3`, you can declare the field your bindable depends on within the `@Bindable` annotation.

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Bindable {
  String[] value() default {};
}
```

In your case, you would write your function like this

```
@Bindable("name")
public CharSequence getStyledName(Context ctx) {
    // your existing code
}
```

See https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-dependent-properties-516d3235cd7c

Comment: Did you actually try this? It is still complaining about JavaBeans convention.

Comment: @RobertoB. Yes, I have been using it in prod for some times now.

Answer (score 0):

My experiment is that you can only use @Bindable with the method that does NOT accept the parameter. ex:

```
@Bindable
public String getName() {
...
}

<TextView>
android:text="@{myClass.name}"
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue when my method looks like

```
    @Bindable
    public Boolean isRead() {
        return read;
    }
```

When i changed function's return type to primitive type, it resolved. Maybe it is usefull to someone.

```
    @Bindable
    public boolean isRead() {
        return read;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    singleton = this
}

companion object {
    private var singleton: MyApplication? = null

    fun getInstance(): MyApplication? {
        return singleton
    }
}}
```

Changes in Manifestfile

```
<application
    android:name=".other.MyApplication">
  
</application>
```

Create method in class where you define your baseurl etc..

```
fun getResourceString(resourceId: Int): String? {
        return MyApplication
                .getInstance()!!
                .resources
                .getString(resourceId)
    }
```

And now used this method in BaseObservable class

```
@Bindable
var email:String?=""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.email)
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.emailError)
    }

@get:Bindable
val emailError: String?
    get() = if (email == null || email.toString().trim().isEmpty() || !Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email.toString().trim()).matches())
    {
        AppUtil.getResourceString(R.string.enter_valid_email)
    } else {
        null
    }
```

And in xml file

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/txtLoginEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:text="@={loginUser.email}"
        app:error="@{loginUser.emailError}"/>
```

Hope this one help you..!