# Full example or tutorial about how to get Context from data binding android

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-context

I'm a beginner in android. I have a problem like this issue
[Android DataBinding where to get context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374483/android-databinding-where-to-get-context)
Need to get context for formatting date and time of textview with data binding in correctly ways. However I don't understand the answer clearly. Anyone helps me to get context from data binding in correctly ways.

Comment: MM have you read this  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: @Charuක I read it but how do I get the context to format date time in databinding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to format date and time is with String formatting. For example, you can use this:

```
<TextView android:text="@{@string/dateFormat(user.birthday)}" .../>
```

Where the dateFormat is a resource like this:

```
<string name="dateFormat">%1$td/%1$tm/%1$tY</string>
```

And the birthday is a long. You should look at the [date formatter documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for more formatting information related to time and date.

In [Android DataBinding where to get context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374483/android-databinding-where-to-get-context), I gave one option, but hinted at one that is now also available. You may use the built-in `context` variable, which is the Context of the root View:

```
<TextView android:text="@{Converters.formatDate(context, user.birthday, dateFlags)}" .../>
```

Then your Converters class would have something like this:

```
public class Converters {
    public static String formatDate(Context context, long timeMillis, int dateFlags) {
        return DateUtils.formatDateTime(view.getContext(), timeMillis,
             dateFlags)
    }
}
```

But I recommend the first as it is easy, flexible, and uses less code. It doesn't fix your date and time formats to a single locale.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. However, I see the second help me to get the current date setting of the device. The first will help me to do that ?
However when I put the
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{Converters.formatDate(context, viewModel.date)}"/>
The compiler doesnt  understand, it throws 
data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. Converters is missing it

Comment: I added the <import type="com.example.hiennguyen.beatbox.Converters" /> to the <data> tag, and it'is working. However may you mind to explain the first way can get the current date setting of device ?

Comment: You can pass in the current time with `@{@string/dateFormat(System.currentTimeMillis())}` I think that is what you mean.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try it