# Data binding: How pass Context in xml to method?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Android Studio 3.0.

Here my custom method:

```
public static int getTileWidthDpInScreen(Context context) {
    // some code here
    return tileWidthDp;
}
```

here my xml file with data binding code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="com.myproject.android.customer.util.GUIUtil" />

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@{GUIUtil.getTileWidthDpInScreen()}"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />       


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

And as result I get error:

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
data binding error msg:cannot find method getTileWidthDpInScreen() in class com.myproject.android.customer.util.GUIUtil
```

This error because I'm not pass context in method `getTileWidthDpInScreen()`.

How I get context in xml and pass it in method: `getTileWidthDpInScreen()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374483/android-databinding-where-to-get-context

Comment: OK. It's work:  `A special variable named context is generated for use in binding expressions as needed. The value for context is the Context from the root View's getContext(). The context variable will be overridden by an explicit variable declaration with that name`. So as result here work code: `android:layout_width="@{GUIUtil.getTileWidthDpInScreen(context)}"`

Comment: HAPPY TO HELP YOU @alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android DataBinding where to get context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374483/android-databinding-where-to-get-context)

Answer (score 19):

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) say :

> A special variable named `context` is generated for use in binding
>   expressions as needed. The value for context is the `Context` object
>   from the root View's `getContext()` method. The `context` variable is
>   overridden by an explicit variable declaration with that name.

So the solution is : 
`android:layout_width="@{GUIUtil.getTileWidthDpInScreen(context)}`

Answer (score 6):

You just have to import `<import type="android.content.Context" />` in your xml data imports.

Then, you can access context for your databinding simply with `context`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <import type="android.content.Context" />

        <import type="com.myproject.android.customer.util.GUIUtil" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@{GUIUtil.getTileWidthDpInScreen(context)}"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: It is not necessary to import Context, data binding already adds the variable context to the scope